# Using 2nd router as extension of my main router, LAN works but WLAN doesn't and after "x" time it just refuses to work at all

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bridge

I recently followed a guide how to use an old router to extend my network at [home.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5QJb3O19zI) Everything was smooth, made sure the range I have set the DHCP Server won't conflict with anything (Main Router, from my ISP.) I've used ***192.168.1.30 - 192.168.1.254***.

Moving on to the old router. I've disabled it's DHCP so it wouldn't conflict with the server, set the old router's IP Address as ***192.168.1.15***. I've setup the wireless options as well, made sure it has a different SSID, even changed the channel selection so it wouldn't collide with anything. The LAN interface works, at the moment I'm connected to it as I'm typing this question. The only problem I've had is whenever an I try to connect to it wirelessly via an Android or iPhone it has limited connectivity. I am connected to the network, but I do not have an internet, the LAN ports work however. The 2nd/old router acts like a switch it seems. Any advice how to set this up properly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected the secondary router via one of its LAN ports, or its WAN port? It won't work right if it's through the WAN port - if you do that it will try to route traffic in a way that will cause limited connectivity. Plug the router into one of the LAN ports and it should work.

Also, make sure your DHCP server's default gateway is set to the primary router's IP.